# How can I make a rigid body interact with a fluid simulation?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

I am confused as to why the rigid body sphere is not making any sort of splash when it hits the fluid. I have the "export as animated mesh
 box checked, but that did not change anything.

I would really appreciate anyone who could help me solve this.

[Here is the link to the .blend](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hJe8kXWMsAJ8D-7IUllh9inXv4ocCTVP?usp=sharing)

This is my first post on stack exchange, sorry if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Did you add to this Rigid Body: Fluid > Obstacle?

Comment: @LukeD yes I did.